# How to update nested object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am rather new to mongodb and self learning. Since recently I am a bit stuck on this one. I would like to update a nested document. I worked around it by retrieving the full document and updating the entire thing, but I need a solution where I can update in a single shot. I made the following simplified example:

```
db.test.insert({
    'name': 'someSchool',
    'classes': [
        {
            'name': 'someClass', 
            'students': [
                {
                    'name': 'Jack',
                    'coolness' : 7
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Here the arrays only have one entry for simplicity, you understand we normally have more...

```
db.test.find({
    'name' : 'someSchool', 
    'classes' : { 
        $elemMatch: {
            'name': 'someClass',
            'students.name' : 'Jack'
        }
    }
});
```

This find works! Thats great, so now I want to use it in an update, which is where Im stuck. Something like this??

```
db.test.update({
    'name' : 'someSchool', 
    'classes' : { 
        $elemMatch: {
            'name': 'someClass',
            'students.name' : 'Jack'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$set' : { 'classes.students.coolness' : 9}
});
```

So this doesnt work and now I am stuck at it :) Hopefully someone here can help.

Side note: I am using mongoose. If you guys tell me its better to change the schema to make it easier somehow, I can.

Update since marked as duplicate: In the referenced question, there is only 1 level of nesting and the problem gets solved by using dot notation. Here there are 2 levels. I accepted teh answer which explains it is not supported and which gives a correct workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pull sub-documents from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564195/how-can-i-pull-sub-documents-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays) it's not possible right now to update two level nested arrays.

I would suggest you to change your schema in order to replace one level array nesting with object. So your document would look like this:

```
{
    "name" : "someSchool",
    "classes" : {
            "someClass" : {
                    "students" : [
                            {
                                    "name" : "Jack",
                                    "coolness" : 7
                            }
                    ]
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update specific array element. But be aware that positional operator updates only the first element in array that matches the query.

Update query would look like this:

```
db.test.update({ 
  'classes.someClass.students' : {          
     $elemMatch: {
       'name' : 'Jack'         
     }     
   } 
}, {     
  '$set' : { 
    'classes.someClass.students.$.coolness' : 9
   } 
});
```