# Remove Object from Nested Array by Multiple Criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this schema document in mongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": UUID("cf397865-c000-4f51-8959-1aae84769706"),
    "CreationDateTime": ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:14.589Z"),
    "WKT": "",
    "Distributions": [{
            "_id": UUID("bb95bedb-4baa-4ada-90b1-0d763e70ebfe"),
            "DeliveryType": 1,
            "DistributionData": [{
                    "Key": "Topic",
                    "Value": "Topics",
                    "Children": null
                }, {
                    "Key": null,
                    "Value": null,
                    "Children": null
                }, {
                    "Key": "Message",
                    "Value": "test",
                    "Children": null
                }
            ],
            "Schedules": [
                ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:56.988Z")
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to cleaning my database.So in order to i have decided deleted null objects in `DistributionData`.How can i delete object that all three attributes have a null value  :

```
 {
  "Key": null,
  "Value": null,
  "Children": null
 }.
```

I wrote this query :

```
db.Events.update(
    {},
    {$pull:
        {
            results: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "Distributions[0].DistributionData" : {$in:[null]}
                }
            }
        }
     },
     { multi: true }
)
```

When i execute this query nothing happends! I know `$elemMatch` is mistake..
Now how can i remove json object that all feild is null in `DistributionData`??
I read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228210/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-doubly-nested-array-in-a-mongodb-document) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564195/how-can-i-pull-sub-documents-from-an-array) but make me Confused...

> Edit

I wrote this query:

```
db.Events.update(
    {},
    {$pull:
        {
            Distributions : {
                DistributionData:{
                $elemMatch: {
                    "Key" : null
                }
              }
            }
        }
     },
     { multi: true }
)
```

This query will remove completely object inside Distributions that `DistributionData` array had an object with null key:

**Result**:

```
{
"_id": UUID("cf397865-c000-4f51-8959-1aae84769706"),
"CreationDateTime": ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:14.589Z"),
"WKT" : "",
"Distributions" : [],...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) the "first match" from the "outer array" with removing "all the inner elements" simply by doing:

```
db.Events.updateMany(
  {
    "Distributions.DistributionData": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "Key": null,
        "Value": null,
        "Children": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "Distributions.$.DistributionData": { 
        "Key": null,
        "Value": null,
        "Children": null
      }
    }
  }
)
```

That is fine if you only ever have one entry in  the `"Distributions"` array or at least only one of those entries has child array entries which would match the condition. This is how the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) works with all versions of MongoDB.

If the data would have "multiple" matches in the "outer" `"Distributions"` array then if you have MongoDB 3.6 you can apply the [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to modify all matched entries:

```
db.Events.updateMany(
  {
    "Distributions.DistributionData": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "Key": null,
        "Value": null,
        "Children": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "Distributions.$[element].DistributionData": { 
        "Key": null,
        "Value": null,
        "Children": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "element.DistributionData": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Key": null,
          "Value": null,
          "Children": null
        }
      }}
    ]
  }
)
```

In that case the `arrayFilters` option defines a condition by which we match entries in the "outer" array so that this can in fact apply to everything which is matched.

Or indeed since [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) essentially has those conditions itself, then you can alternately just use the [positional all `$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator in this case:

```
db.Event.updateMany(
  {
    "Distributions.DistributionData": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "Key": null,
        "Value": null,
        "Children": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "Distributions.$[].DistributionData": { 
        "Key": null,
        "Value": null,
        "Children": null
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Either case changes the document in the question by removing the inner item with all `null` keys:

```
{
        "_id" : UUID("cf397865-c000-4f51-8959-1aae84769706"),
        "CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:14.589Z"),
        "WKT" : "",
        "Distributions" : [
                {
                        "_id" : UUID("bb95bedb-4baa-4ada-90b1-0d763e70ebfe"),
                        "DeliveryType" : 1,
                        "DistributionData" : [
                                {
                                        "Key" : "Topic",
                                        "Value" : "Topics",
                                        "Children" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "Key" : "Message",
                                        "Value" : "test",
                                        "Children" : null
                                }
                        ],
                        "Schedules" : [
                                ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:56.988Z")
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

The "query" conditions all use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for document selection. This is actually required for the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in order to obtain the "position index" used for the "first match". Whilst this is not actually a "requirement" for either the [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) or the [positional all `$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator, it is still useful so you don't even consider documents for update which will not match the later update conditions of either the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) or the `arrayFilters` options.

As for the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) itself, the conditions here actually apply to "each" array element, so there is no need for the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in that operation since we are already looking at the "element" level.

The third example shows that the [positional all `$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator can simply use those [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) conditions in consideration of each "inner" array element and will just apply to ALL "outer" array elements. So the actual point of the [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) expression is to "only" process those "outer" array elements which actually match the "inner" condition. Hence why we use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in the consideration for matching each "inner" array element.

---

If you do not actually have MongoDB 3.6 at least then you are using the first form and likely repeating that until the updates finally return no more modified documents indicating that there are no more elements left that match the condition.

There is a much more detailed write up on the "alternatives" as approaches at [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb), but as long as your data either suits the initial case or you actually do have MongoDB 3.6 available, then this is the correct approach here.

---

If you want to see the full effect of the new syntax for MongoDB 3.6. this is the alteration to the document in the question I used to verify the update statements here:

```
{
    "_id" : UUID("cf397865-c000-4f51-8959-1aae84769706"),
    "CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:14.589Z"),
    "WKT" : "",
    "Distributions" : [
            {
                    "_id" : UUID("bb95bedb-4baa-4ada-90b1-0d763e70ebfe"),
                    "DeliveryType" : 1,
                    "DistributionData" : [
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Topic",
                                    "Value" : "Topics",
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : null,
                                    "Value" : null,
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Message",
                                    "Value" : "test",
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : null,
                                    "Value" : null,
                                    "Children" : null
                            }
                    ],
                    "Schedules" : [
                            ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:56.988Z")
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : UUID("bb95bedb-4baa-4ada-90b1-0d763e70ebfe"),
                    "DeliveryType" : 1,
                    "DistributionData" : [
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Topic",
                                    "Value" : "Topics",
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : null,
                                    "Value" : null,
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Message",
                                    "Value" : "test",
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : null,
                                    "Value" : null,
                                    "Children" : null
                            }
                    ],
                    "Schedules" : [
                            ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:56.988Z")
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Which basically duplicates some entries both "outer" and "inner" to show how the statement removes all the `null` values.

> **NOTE** `arrayFilters` are specified in the "options" argument for `.update()` and like methods, the syntax is generally compatible with all recent release driver versions and even those prior to the release of MongoDB 3.6.
>
> However this is not true of the `mongo` shell, since the way the method is implemented there ( "ironically for backward compatibility" ) the `arrayFilters` argument is not recognized and removed by an internal method that parses the options in order to deliver "backward compatibility" with prior MongoDB server versions and a "legacy" `.update()` API call syntax.
>
> So if you want to use the command in the `mongo` shell or other "shell based" products ( notably Robo 3T ) you need a latest version from either the development branch or production release as of 3.6 or greater.
>
> Robo 3T notably here is still tied to being based on a MongoDB 3.4 shell. So even when connecting to a capable MongoDB 3.6 instance, these options will not be passed to the server from this program. It is advised to stay with the shell and supported products only, though there are some other offerings which do not have the same limitation.

Comment: Thanks dude i'll try and announce you soon..@neillunn

Comment: @sayreskabir Glad it helped. Added some more information if you still need more explanation as to why this works.

Comment: I have checked just first your suggestion because i have one entry in the "Distributions". But your Description is complete and i know that, if i have multiple array in `Distributions` your code will worked perfectly.