# How to apply the "arrayFilters" on the top-level array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

My question is similar to [Remove Object from Nested Array by Multiple Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197062/remove-object-from-nested-array-by-multiple-criteria). The major difference is that I want to apply the `arrayFilter` on the top-level array first and then apply another `arrayFilter` on the nested array of the matched top-level array element.

First of all, here is the document sample I copied over from the post with some adjustments to suit my case...

```
{
    "OtherField1" : ISODate("2016-05-06T05:09:14.589Z"),
    "OtherField2" : "something",
    "Distributions" : [
            {
                    "DeliveryType" : 1,
                    "DeliverySubType" : 2,
                    "DistributionData" : [
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Topic",
                                    "Value" : "Topics",
                                    "Children" : null
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Message",
                                    "Value" : "test",
                                    "Children" : null
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "DeliveryType" : 1,
                    "DeliverySubType" : 3,
                    "DistributionData" : [
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Topic",
                                    "Value" : "Topics",
                                    "Children" : ""
                            },
                            {
                                    "Key" : "Message",
                                    "Value" : "test",
                                    "Children" : null
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to, first of all, locate the 2nd element of the top-level `Distributions` array by matching `"DeliveryType" : 1` and `"DeliverySubType" : 3`, and then locate the 1st element of its nested `DistributionData` array by matching `"Key": "Topic"` and `"Value" : "Topics"`, and finally update the `Children` field of matched nested array element.

For the top-level match, I tried the following forms ...

```
{
  "arrayFilters": [
  { "filter1" : {
      "elemMatch" : {
         "DeliveryType" : 1,
         "DeliverySubType" : 3,
       }
     }
  }
}
```

and referenced the filter as `Distributions.$[filter1]...`, but it didn't work.
Or,

```
{
  "arrayFilters": [
  { "filter1.Distributions" : {
      "elemMatch" : {
         "DeliveryType" : 1,
         "DeliverySubType" : 3,
       }
     }
  }
}
```

and referenced the filter as `$[filter1].Distributions....`, but once again it failed with a parsing error.

All the examples I can found are about using the `arrayFilters` on the nested arrays and myself had some success in that regard, but no matter how hard I tried to apply the same tricks to the filters on the top-level array, they just failed with all sorts of errors. Could anyone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is somewhat hidden but it's actually [documented](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html#update-all-array-elements-that-match-multiple-conditions):

```
db.collection.update({}, {
    $set: { "Distributions.$[distFilter].DistributionData.$[distDataFilter].Children": "new value" }
    }, {
    "arrayFilters": [
        {
            "distFilter.DeliveryType" : 1,
            "distFilter.DeliverySubType" : 3
        }, {
            "distDataFilter.Key" : "Topic",
            "distDataFilter.Value" : "Topics"
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Further question, rather than listing key properties, is there any other syntax to use object notation like `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}`? Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any.