# How can I remove an element that is contained in the third level of an array?

Tags: mongodb

my database has a structure like this:

```
  {
    "universe": "comics",
    "saga": [
      {
        "name": "x-men",
        "characters": [
          {
            "character": "wolverine",
            "powers": [
              {
                "power": "self-recovery"
              },
              {
                "power": "Super strength"
              },
              {
                "power": "steels claws"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "character": "cyclops",
            "powers": [
              {
                "power": "rays"
              },
              {
                "power": "Super strength"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "universe": "comics",
    "saga": [
      {
        "name": "spiderman",
        "characters": [
          {
            "character": "venom",
            "powers": [
              {
                "power": "Super strength"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I basically want to learn how to do operations with complex arrays, this time I think I will learn too much if I get the answer to this question.
I want to delete the objects where `"power:"self-recovery"`

something like `$.saga.characters.$.powers`

I don't know how to do it because of the number of levels this property is under the main root.

normally i would use something like that:

```
db.mydb.update(
    {
    saga: {
        $elemMatch: { saga.characters.$ },
    },
    },

    { $pull: { powers: { power: "Super strength"
    } }},
    {
    new: true,
    multi:true
    },
```

for this example it should delete as many objects where `{" power ":" self-recovery"}` (in this case, only one object is deleted, which is where the character is `wolverine`)

but i don't know how to do what i need.

Comment: try `updateMany` and look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50197290/8987128 just need to put your object keys as per operation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the positional all [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator in MongoDb 3.6+

```
var query = {
    universe: 'comics'
};

var update = {
    $pull: {
        'saga.$[].characters.$[].powers': {
            power: 'self-recovery'
        }
    }
};
var options = {
    multi: true
};
db.collection.update(query, update, options);
```

Comment: what means "$[]"? is neccesary put "[]"

Comment: $[] applies the pull operation for all the sub-documents inside the array which matches the criteria

Comment: thanks! if i just use the `$` operator without `[]` won't it work?

Comment: can you help me with this please? this question has a bounty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988071/how-can-i-return-the-element-im-looking-for-inside-a-nested-array/63029063#63029063

Answer (score 0):

```
db.test.update(
  {
    "saga.characters.powers": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "power": "self-recovery"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "saga.$[].characters.$.powers": { 
       "power":"self-recovery"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

It removes the respective power object.It results

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f11e25a9e001b53e39985fd"),
    "universe" : "comics",
    "saga" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "x-men",
            "characters" : [ 
                {
                    "character" : "wolverine",
                    "powers" : [ 
                        {
                            "power" : "Super strength"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "power" : "steels claws"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "character" : "cyclops",
                    "powers" : [ 
                        {
                            "power" : "rays"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "power" : "Super strength"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Kindly check and let me know missing things